# How to open React Component based on remaining width on right side of x-axis

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, calendar, width

**Background:**I am creating a custom daterange picker component in React and want it to open right by default and open left if width on right hand side is not sufficient for complete two-month window to show?

**Question:**Is there a way in CSS/SASS/JS to determine remaining width and put a logic based on that?

Happy to provide more info, if needed. Please help.

**Current scenario:**Currently I have hardcoded it open right on certain screens and left on others. But would need a more cleaner, generic approach.

**Additional info:** The container of calendar has calendar plus some other info-based component arranged using CSS grid.

Comment: You would need to get the x position of the button that opens up the component with `getBoundingClientRect()`, add the width of the two-month windows to it, and check if that result is greater than or less than `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. If it's greater, you can place it at x position of button minus the width of two windows.